# DRF form render object property (name) instead of Object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

The form select option is showing 'survey object' - how can I get it to render the surveyname instead? The lookupfield is using the survey object 'name' property - how can I get the POST form to also use it?

```
<option value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/surveys/mysurvey/">Survey object</option>
<option value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/surveys/anothersurvey/">Survey object</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Survery object" is the default representation for your model. So somewhere in your model `Survery` you have to define its string representation, e.g.

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):     # or def __unicode__(self) in Python 2
        return self.name
```

In Python 2 Django will call `__unicode__()` on your model. In Python 3, it will call `__str__()`

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks so much - I was using __unicode__ & python3!